# How to protect microphone in rain while recording frog calls?

Tags: audio-recording, equipment, animals, outdoor

What is the best, inexpensive way to protect my Behringer ECM 8000 microphone from rain while attempting to record frog calls outdoors? I am a graduate student with no funding, so inexpensive is important, but current attempts at cover result in just loud pelting noise from the rain itself. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you searched here for previous answers? This type of question has been as before: [http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/waterproof-covering-for-microphones](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/waterproof-covering-for-microphones) You can also use the tags to locate topics that have been discussed before:

Comment: Non lubricated condoms can protect your mic from water.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waterproof covering for microphones](http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7642/waterproof-covering-for-microphones)

Answer (score 1):

Protecting microphones from rain is quite a challenge, and I haven't found the perfect solution either yet: it is not only about protecting the microphone itself from damage, but also getting rid of the sound of the rain drop impacts straight on the mic and its windshield/foam.

The best results I have achieved so far when recording rain was by putting the mic on a small stand (like for micing a kick drum) and then placing myself over it holding a thick blanket with my arms stretched out. Looks quite awkward, lasts only for a few minutes in strong rain and may cause some back pain after a while :-).

If your focus is on recording the frogs though anyway, I would rather wait for better weather instead. Even if you manage to isolate your mic from the rain drop impacts, you will get a lot of rain sounds and other ambience on top with an omni like the ECM8000; maybe you can rent a more directional microphone like a shotgun or at least a hypercardioid?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a fabric which is known as Hogs Hair. This material will absorb the droplets of water as they hit and will disperse them, protecting them mic from both the liquid and also the sound of the liquid. Assuming you are using a Rycote or Rode blimp, you can cover the top of the blip with hogs hair to protect the microphone and blimp. This is a common solution used in film-making when filming outdoors in the rain.